# How to process large file using pipeline from transformers

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, openai-whisper

I load model from Hugging Face using pipeline:

```
device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
torch_dtype = torch.float16 if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.float32

model_id = "openai/whisper-large-v3"

model = AutoModelForSpeechSeq2Seq.from_pretrained(
    model_id, torch_dtype=torch_dtype, low_cpu_mem_usage=True, use_safetensors=True
)
model.to(device)

processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id)

pipe = pipeline(
    "automatic-speech-recognition",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=processor.tokenizer,
    feature_extractor=processor.feature_extractor,
    max_new_tokens=128,
    chunk_length_s=20,
    batch_size=16,
    return_timestamps=True,
    torch_dtype=torch_dtype,
    device=device,
)
```

And i want to process big audio file

```
result = pipe("filename3.mp3")
```

But google collab says i ran out of RAM. Is it possible to pipe output to file rather than variable?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The Whisper `large` model is several Gb in size - often larger than a single GPU RAM. If you have insufficient GPU RAM on one GPU, you may need to spread the model over multiple GPUs, if available, using `torch.nn`'s function `nn.DataParallel`.

Alternatively, you may need to use the smaller `medium` model.